# Validating user input Monotouch

Tags: validation, xamarin.ios

I have a Monotouch app that is essentially a large questionnaire that has perhaps 100 to 200 text inputs, checkboxes, date picks etc. A large number are validated to ensure appropriate data is entered, selecting which sections need to be completed depending on answers etc.

Are there tool kits to assist with individual field validation and validation of whole collection (screen) of data that would work with Monotouch?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any specific tools to validate input.  Your best bet is probably to extend MonoTouch.Dialog to include new cell types that have the input validation logic you need.